# Clearing /tmp directory in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is this correct, that `/tmp` directory in **hdfs** is authomatically clearing every 24 hours (by default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HDFS** **/tmp** directory is mainly used as a temporary storage during mapreduce operation. Mapreduce artifacts, intermediate data etc will be kept under this directory. These files should be automatically cleared out when mapreduce job execution completes. If you delete this temporary files, it can affect the currently running mapreduce jobs.

Temporary files are created by pig. Temporary files deletion happens at the end. Pig does not handles temporary files deletion if the script execution filed or killed. Then you got to handles this situation. You better handle this temporary files clean up activity in the script itself.

Comment: Your answer resembles [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888117/5749570)